# Java Apache Commons Net SMTP Wrapper Attachment

Tags: java, android, file, io, email

Can the below code be improved? Are there any major issues with it?
Thanks

```
Writer w = client.sendMessageData();
for (File file : myAttachments) {
    w.append("\r\n").append("--").append(bound).append("\r\n");
    w.append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n");
    w.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n");
    w.append("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" + Tools.getNameForAttach(file.getName()) + "\"\r\n\r\n");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int nRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];

    while ((nRead = fileInputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
    }

    buffer.flush();

    fileInputStream.close();

    w.append(Base64.encodeBase64String(buffer.toByteArray()));
    w.append("\r\n");

}
w.close();
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using the [Java Mail API](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home)? Makes this sort of thing much easier... `for (File f : myAttachments) {body.attachFile(f.getPath());}`

Comment: This is for an Android application and Java mail has a lot of dependencies which make app larger

Comment: Note that Apache Commons Mail API internally uses the javax.mail.* classes: [MultiPartMail](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/MultiPartEmail.html#addPart(javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart))

Comment: This is not Commons Mail but Commons Net with AuthenticatingSMTPClient

Comment: You need to include the relevant information in your question. While you are adding the details of your dependencies (put in a link to the API's you are using), you should also include the Base64 implementaiton you are using.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time here. Base64 uses import org.apache.commons.net.util.Base64;

Answer (score 1):

**SRP - single responsibility principle**

The code is violating the SRP, as it does to many things.

It is

1. adding/composing headers for the attachments
2. reading files from disc

I would extract the composition of the headers to a separate method.

```
private String getHeaders() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("\r\n").append("--").append(bound).append("\r\n");
    sb.append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n");
    sb.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n");
    sb.append("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

and would assign the result before the `for` loop to a `String` variable.

Next we extract the file reading to a separate method. I don't know if `Android` supports [Try with resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) so I don't use it here. We also rename the `int nRead` to `bytesRead`.

```
private byte[] readFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];

    while ((bytesRead= fileInputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        buffer.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    buffer.flush();
    fileInputStream.close();

    return buffer.toByteArray();
}
```

next, we add a method which takes a file and returns the content as `base64 encoded string`

```
private String getContentAsBase64(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    byte[] fileContent = readFile(file);

    return Base64.encodeBase64String(fileContent);
}
```

After using the fluent `append()` method instead of the string adding using `+`, this leads to the former code beeing refactored to

```
Writer w = client.sendMessageData();
String attachmentHeader = getAttachmentHeader();
for (File file : myAttachments) {
    w.append(attachmentHeader);
    w.append(Tools.getNameForAttach(file.getName()));
    w.append("\"\r\n\r\n");
    w.append(getContentAsBase64(file));
    w.append("\r\n");
}
w.close();
```